# Can HighCharts LazyLoad a whole new series when clicking the LEGEND?

Tags: highcharts, lazy-loading

I wanna show several series in one chart, and I only wanna the first series to be shown by default. The other series's data shouldn't be fetched until the according legend is clicked, so that the loading speed will be faster.

Only when the according Legend is clicked, then the chart will use AJAX to fetch data and show it, Can highcharts do that?

I have seen several similar questions about lazyload, but they are all using highstock, can highcharts.js do it?

Comment: The lazy-loading solution, loads data on changing extremes not legend. In your case, lets init a chart with all series (only first have data) and catch [legendItemClick event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) to call ajax and update the right series.

Comment: Thanks. If I want each legend's FIRST click to call ajax and show the selected series, and the FOLLOWING clicks to toggle/untoggle the series. Can highcharts or js do this? It needs to remember the current state of the legend, is there any example in jsfiddle? I am not very familier to js, if there is an example, it will be much easier for me to  modify my website. Thanks again. @sebastian-bochan

Comment: You should still catch legendItemClick and add conditions which checks if data extis, if yes, call show/hide. If not, use ajax and update series.